# Unit test that can assert the visibility of a method (rust)

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I would like to write a unit test that asserts that a method is private. The test has visibility to the method and can execute and test it.

The additional test I want is in order to confirm that the method remains private, i.e. I want to be able to fail a test if a future coder (or myself) "accidentally" changes the visibility to pub. Making the method public would break the design because it would allow clients of the implementation to change the struct in a way that would violate assumptions made in the rest of the design.

Is there some type of introspection or reflection that will allow this?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to check if a test fails compilation, but you could write a [documentation test](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html) that uses the `compile_fail` [attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes) to assert that the method is not accessible outside the _crate_.

Comment: I would like the test to compile, and when run be able to check the visibility of the method outside the crate. Maybe that information isn't available at runtime.

Comment: Visibility is a compile-time property, there is no notion of it at runtime.

Comment: This might be better suited to a [static code analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html) run as part of your test suite and configured to detect such a case. That said, such a test may be of little value. Martin Fowler's [*Public Verses Published Interfaces*](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf) might help understand why.

Comment: Is the concern merely that a client might notice an undocumented public method and start to rely on it? In which case I'd say their fault for using an undocumented method; just because it's public doesn't mean its part of the stable API, and without documentation you made no promises. Or is there an additional concern?

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I've run into the same problem when trying to provide hard-to-misuse APIs. For example, maybe a `Admin` struct represents a guarantee that the current session token has been checked to belong to an admin user, and you want to have a test to make sure you can't just use struct-literal syntax to arbitrarily create one. In such a case, a test to check that something doesn't compile can be quite valuable IMO

Comment: @Schwern The question was more out of curiosity if such a test could be written to add an additional warning in the unlikely case that something changed that broke the design. It would only take a minute to write, and could potentially avoid problems later. In any case, it can be noted in the comments and (eventual) design documents. It's less a concern about clients using an undocumented method, more about guarding against overzealous refactoring. Thanks for the link to the article.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, field/function visibility is a concept that only exists at compile time, so you will need to find a way to test that some code fails to compile.

Doctests are a obvious tool, but are somewhat of a sledgehammer solution. I'd recommend the `trybuild` crate instead. I've mostly seen it used by macro authors, but it can generally be useful whenever you want to test that something either does or doesn't compile.

An example usage might be:

```rust
// src/lib.rs (could be anywhere really, it just needs to be a regular #[test] function)
#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn ui_tests() {
  let t = trybuild::TestCases::new();
  t.compile_fail("tests/fail/*.rs");
}

// tests/fail/private_field_access.rs
fn main() {
  let my_struct = MyStruct::new();
  println!("{}", my_struct.private_field);
}
```

This will generate a corresponding `.stderr` file that you can check into version control (similar to rustc's "ui" tests). When the tests are run, the file is compiled, and the output from the compiler is compared against the actual error.

This means you can catch regressions in a more fine-grained way than a simple binary "does it compile" check. For example, if you accidentally made the private field public, the above test may still fail to compile for some other reason (perhaps it doesn't implement `Display`). `trybuild` catches those regressions in a way that `compile-fail` doctests cannot.

When it comes time to generate the `.stderr` files, you can run `TRYBUILD=overwrite cargo test` to overwrite the existing files.

It's worth mentioning that `trybuild` tests (like doctests) only work for the external API of your *crate*, not module. If that's an issue, you could consider using cargo workspaces and a multi-crate setup (there are other reasons this might be preferable, e.g. compile times).